# Get x-values corresponding to y-value on non-monotonic curves

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, curve-fitting

First, I'm not sure SO is the good place to ask this kind of question.
If not please tell me where to ask and I'll remove it.

However, since I not found any post that address my problem, my question and my code below may be useful to other people ...

The code part is a bit long, although I tried to keep only the minimum.
However, this part should only serves to show that I have done some research and that I am looking for something better.

**The question:**

From a x-values and y-values lists, I want to find (or guess) the x-values which corresponds to a given y-value.

When the curve defined by X and Y values is **monotonic**, I can simply interpolate the function `x = f(y)` :

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

class AxisCam:
    def __init__(self, x=None, y=None):
        self.x = x if x else []
        self.y = y if y else []

        if len(self.x):
            self.xMin = min(self.x)
            self.xMax = max(self.x)
        else:
            self.xMin = None
            self.xMax = None

        if len(self.y):
            self.yMin = min(self.y)
            self.yMax = max(self.y)
        else:
            self.yMin = None
            self.yMax = None

        self._interpolX, self._interpolY = self.setInterpolator()

    def setInterpolator(self, interpolator=interpolate.interp1d):
        """
        Define the interpolator to use to approximate the axis cam positions
        :param interpolator: interpolator function to use, default is scipy.interpolate.interp1d
        :return: a tuple with the interpolator functions for x and y values
        """
        if len(self.x) <= 0 or len(self.y) <= 0:
            return None, None
        with np.errstate(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore'):  # silent the warnings caused by the interpolator
            self._interpolX = interpolator(self.y, self.x)  # x = f(y)
            self._interpolY = interpolator(self.x, self.y)  # y = f(x)
        return self._interpolX, self._interpolY

    def getX(self, yValue):
        """
        Return x-value corresponding to a y-value using the interpolator
        :param yValue: y-value we want to know the corresponding x-value
        :return: x-value corresponding to the given y-value
        """
        if yValue < self.yMin:
            raise ValueError("value should be greater than the minimum y-value")
        elif yValue > self.yMax:
            raise ValueError("value should be lesser than the maximum y-value")
        return float(self._interpolX(yValue))

    def getY(self, value):
        """
        Return a y-value corresponding to a x-value using the interpolator
        :param value: x-value we want to know the corresponding y-value
        :return: the y-value corresponding to the given x-value
        """
        if value < self.xMin:
            raise ValueError("value should be greater than the minimum x-value")
        elif value > self.xMax:
            raise ValueError("value should be lesser than the maximum x-value")
        return float(self._interpolY(value))

x = [0, 0.351906, 0.703812, 1.055718]  # The 1024 values for X and Y can be retrieved here : https://pastebin.com/5eHsRjZ3
y = [0.0, 0.000306, 0.002419, 0.008111]
ac = AxisCam(x, y)
print(ac.getX(100))  # returns 30.124163768271398
```

However, when the curve is **non-monotonic**, I can't. An exception is raised

> ValueError: x must be strictly increasing

So, for now, I splitted the curve into monotonics part using `getMonotonicParts` method below and I can interpolate the function `x = f(y)` on each monotonic parts.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

class AxisCam:
    def __init__(self, x=None, y=None):
        self.x = x if x else []
        self.y = y if y else []

        if len(self.y):
            self.yMin = min(self.y)
            self.yMax = max(self.y)
        else:
            self.yMin = None
            self.yMax = None

        self._monotonicParts = self.getMonotonicParts()

    def getMonotonicParts(self, interpolator=interpolate.interp1d):
        parts = []
        prevY = None  # will store the previous value of y to compare with at each iteration
        startIdx = None  # will store the index of self.x and self.y where the monotonic part start from
        direction = 0  # 0: Unknown - 1 : constant - 2: ascending - 3: descending
        lenY = len(self.y)
        for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(self.x, self.y)):
            if prevY is None:
                prevY = y
            if startIdx is None:
                startIdx = i

            prevDir = direction
            direction = 1 if y == prevY else 2 if y > prevY else 3
            if prevDir != 0 and prevDir != direction:  # Direction has changed => we have a new monotonic part
                endIdx = i - 1
                if direction == 3:  # y values are increasing => we can interpolate on it
                    interp_func = interpolator(self.y[startIdx:endIdx], self.x[startIdx:endIdx])
                elif direction == 1:  # y values are decreasing => we need to reverse it to interpolate on it
                    xValues = self.x[startIdx:endIdx]
                    xValues.reverse()
                    yValues = self.y[startIdx:endIdx]
                    yValues.reverse()
                    interp_func = interpolator(yValues, xValues)
                else:  # y values are the same on the range => return one of these
                    def interp_func(value): return self.y[startIdx]
                parts.append({'start': startIdx,
                              'end': endIdx,
                              'x0': self.x[startIdx],
                              'y0': self.y[startIdx],
                              'x1': self.x[endIdx],
                              'y1': self.y[endIdx],
                              'interp': interp_func})
                startIdx = i
            elif i == lenY - 1:  # Add element on the last iteration
                endIdx = i
                if direction == 2:
                    interp = interpolator(self.y[startIdx:endIdx], self.x[startIdx:endIdx])
                else:
                    interp = None
                parts.append({'start': startIdx,
                              'end': endIdx,
                              'x0': self.x[startIdx],
                              'y0': self.y[startIdx],
                              'x1': self.x[endIdx],
                              'y1': self.y[endIdx],
                              'interp': interp})
            prevY = y
        return parts

    def getX(self, yValue):
        """
        Return a list of x-values corresponding to a y-value using the interpolator
        :param yValue: y-value we want to know the corresponding x-value
        :return: a list of x-values corresponding to the given y-value
        """
        if yValue < self.yMin:
            raise ValueError("value should be greater than the minimum y-value")
        elif yValue > self.yMax:
            raise ValueError("value should be lesser than the maximum y-value")
        xValues = []
        for part in self._monotonicParts:
            if part['y0'] <= yValue <= part['y1'] or part['y0'] >= yValue >= part['y1']:
                xValues.append(float(part['interp'](yValue)))
        return xValues

x = []  # The 1024 values for X and Y can be retrieved here : https://pastebin.com/SL9RYYxY
y = []  # /!\ It is not the same values that the previous example /!\
ac = AxisCam(x, y)
print(ac.getX(100))  # returns [122.96996037206237, 207.6239552142487]
```

My solution works quite well but seems a bit far-fetched to me and I'm wondering if there is another better methods to do this.

Comment: Seems like what you need is spline interpolation? You can use `scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline`, for example

Comment: @tiago no. If I use any kind of interpolator "as this", I get `ValueError: x must be strictly increasing`

Comment: If that is the case, then `f(y)` is not a function because for a given value of x you can have more than one value of y.

Comment: @tiago Exactly. That's why in case of non-monotonic curve, I can't use interpolation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any standard routine to do this kind of multi-interpolation. But if you want this to scale, you should refactor your code a bit to use everything that numpy offers. For example, you could do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

# convert data lists to arrays
x, y = np.array(x), np.array(y)

# sort x and y by x value
order = np.argsort(x)
xsort, ysort = x[order], y[order]

# compute indices of points where y changes direction
ydirection = np.sign(np.diff(ysort))
changepoints = 1 + np.where(np.diff(ydirection) != 0)[0]

# find groups of x and y within which y is monotonic
xgroups = np.split(xsort, changepoints)
ygroups = np.split(ysort, changepoints)
interps = [interp1d(y, x, bounds_error=False) for y, x in zip(ygroups, xgroups)]

# interpolate all y values
yval = 100
xvals = np.array([interp(yval) for interp in interps])

print(xvals)
# array([          nan,  122.96996037,  207.62395521,           nan])
```

Here `nan` indicates a value that is out of range (this algorithm treats repeated values as a separate group).

Comment: Oh nice ! I knew I missed something but numpy is still a little obscure for me. Thanks !

Comment: I noticed one issue with this algorithm when `y` has 2 (and only 2) same consecutive values. In this case, `ygroups` contains an array with only one element and `interp1d` need at least 2 elements.
To fix it, I modified the list-comp as follows : `interps = [interpolator(y, x, bounds_error=False) for y, x in zip(yGroups, xGroups) if len(y) >= 2]`